# Connected run-time RSS to TwitterFeed

Tags: php, rss, twitter, twitter-feed

I am creating RSS at runtime using PHP. I connected the link to TwitterFeed, but it is not submitting tweets to Twitter. Is it compulsory that the URL file name must have the extension .xml?

Comment: Is your feed valid ? (see http://feedvalidator.org/ for instance) ;; do you get any error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `.xml` extension is by no means required.

Without seeing your feed, it is nearly impossible to troubleshoot this. My guess is that your feed contains invalid characters or some other error that's making TwitterFeed's XML parser choke on it. Try running it through the validator at http://feedvalidator.org/ and see what errors crop up.

Comment: The feed is valid. I checked it.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to contact TwitterFeed for support.